# Converting images to video with FFmpeg on-the-fly

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a C application that produces a series of images continuously: frame_1.png, frame_2.png, frame_3.png, etc. The application never stops, which means that the longer it runs the more images it produces. While the application is running I want FFmpeg to convert those images to video on-the-fly. As a result, the longer the application and FFmpeg runs, the larger the output video file should become. FFmpeg should never terminate and should always wait for new frames. How can I achieve that?

For far I have this: `ffmpeg -i "frame_%d.png" output.avi`. Unfortunately, this doesn't really do what I want. It just iterates over the files that exist on the file system at the moment I am executing the FFmpeg command, it generates the video, and terminates after processing the last image.

I also tried to use a FIFO as follows: (1) run `mkfifo fifo.png`. (2) Run the C application. Inside the C application I have something like this in a loop (pseudo-code): `fd = open("fifo.png"); write_new_frame_as_png(fd); close(fd);`. (3) run `ffmpeg -i fifo.png output.avi`. Unfortunately, this doesn't work either. The C application generates one frame and blocks until I run FFmpeg. Then FFmpeg just reads one fame of the FIFO, generates a one-frame video file and terminates.

So my question is, how to tell FFmpeg to generate a video in real time as new frames arrive?

Thank you.

PS: In case you are wondering why I want to do the above: Ultimately, I want to stream live video using FFmpeg and FFserver, and I guess this question covers the first step towards that.

Comment: This *may* work  :- `cat frame_*.png | ffmpeg -f image2pipe -re -i - out.ts`

Comment: Hi @DavidPostill , thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, that answer does not cover how to convert the images to a video. It mostly focuses how to play the video from a client using ffplay. One of the guys provides a link to the Streaming Guide FFmpeg documentation, but even the documentation only covers inputs from capture devices like cameras or inputs using x11grab. It does not, however, provide examples of how to stream images as videos on the fly.

Comment: Hi @Mulvya , thanks for providing that tip. Your solution works only if I generate frames in my C application faster than the image-to-video conversion. If the C application is very slow, for a short period of time FFmpeg does not have any frames to process, and instead of just waiting it terminates. The same happens if I use the `-f image2` argument of FFmpeg instead of `cat`.

Comment: You can adapt the method in the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/q/46602042/5726027 to limit ffmpeg processing speed to your app's speed.

Comment: Asking at [Video.SE](https://video.stackexchange.com/) is likely to provide an answer sooner. Be certain to use the share link to this question when you ask on more than one site, or delete this question.